# JMeter - How to handle Long polling transport request method

Tags: jmeter, long-polling

In my Jmeter script request which contains the 'LongPolling' transport method and it takes a high load time or response time

Also, the response message content value is used for the next consecutive request. How can I handle that scenario?

I don't want this my wait time for the server response

Answer (score 0):

JMeter thread model assumes that a thread (virtual user) always waits for the previous sampler to fully complete before starting the new one.

- The easiest solution is moving your "long-polling" requests into a separate thread group and if you need to pass data between thread groups either use [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) and [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) functions combination or go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)
- If you need to have everything within the single Thread Group - you can consider using [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller), however it might not be fully suitable for your needs as it is still a Sampler hence it waits for all its children completion prior to proceeding
- Depending on your use case you can find [jmeter-asynchronous-http plugin](https://github.com/pleutres/jmeter-asynchronous-http) useful, see [How to Load Test Async Requests with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-async-requests-with-jmeter) article for more details if needed.

Comment: Indeed, but in my scenario, the next sample request required the interaction ID value from the 'Connect' response which takes a high response time'. Also, I have tried the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) plugin too. Which doesn't help that much